# Put current time date in hidden field

Tags: php, javascript

I would like to put the current time/date into a hidden text field with the format 19:19:09 Sep 27, 2011

```
 <input type="hidden" name="current_date" value="" readonly="readonly">
```

Thank you

Comment: No you don't. You want a timestamp.

Comment: are you looking to do this with php or javascript?

Comment: What is the purpose of this, can you elaborate, your necessity.

Comment: just to add date to an input which will be updated to db..

Comment: This seems a bit pointless if the input is on one of your pages and is being submitted back to your server: why don't you just modify your DB update function to set the timestamp at the time you save to the DB? (Or are you specifically trying to measure the time between when the user opened the page and when they got around to pressing submit?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_date" value="<?php echo date('H:i:s M d, Y'); ?>" readonly="readonly">
```

But you should know that the user can change the value easily.

**Edit:**
Use [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) to set the timezone.

The timezone of Australia is listed here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php

Comment: Is this based on the users time/date? or somewhere central?

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
<?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
?>



<input type="hidden" name="current_date" value="<?php echo $today?>" readonly="readonly">
```