# How to set current date with HTML input type Date Tag

Tags: php, html, date

I am new in php and i want to set current date in my HTMl date tag

```
<input type="date" value="Today">
```

How i can get current date?

Comment: Have you searched for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Put current time date in hidden field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577944/put-current-time-date-in-hidden-field)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using `date` function as

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
```

Comment: @eNeMetcH stackoverflow said wait for 7 minutes

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow standard `Y-m-d` format

```
<input type="date"  name="current_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow standard Y-m-d format
Use this.

```
<input type="date"  name="current_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>">
```