# Hidden text field time running

Tags: php, html, mysql, textfield, hidden-field

i m referring to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577944/put-current-time-date-in-hidden-field)

what if hidden field is used as to store time in db while inserting record & the time visitors opens page is : 3:00pm but he inserts records on same page without refreshing & inserts at 3:10pm then results seems to be 3:00pm cause what time was earlier when page was loaded that time appears to be save. So how we keep running time in hidden field!

More information on table structure, & php statements:

Table Name: "Areas"
Columns: ID, Name, AreaName, Position, TimeAdded, TimeUpdated, Deleted

Using php mysql.
Hidden text field contains:

`<input name="TIME" id="TIME" type="hidden" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set("".$row_CompanyDetails['TimeZone']."");echo "".date("Y-m-d G:i:s");?>">`

Now lets say User open page at 2016-02-14 03:34:59
So at hidden field value is : 2016-02-14 03:34:59

So lets say user adds record After few seconds the record shows : 2016-02-14 03:34:59, where as it must show 2016-02-14 03:35:10 or 11 or 12+ ....

So i need the exact value. This is critical for me.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. I added the html tag to your question as that is the most important one in this context. Please also try to keep your sentences short, it helps the reader.

Comment: Which server technology are you using? PHP? ASP? ColdFusion? node.js? ...

Comment: OK, I added that tag as well. Please take care to specify the relevant tags when you ask a question. The php and html tags are much more important here than the ones you put.

Comment: Reminder: Please also tag which database engine you use: MySql? SQL Server? Oracle? Postgres? ... And provide the PHP statement with which you insert the data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

Your application server should not rely on the time stamp posted from a hidden input.

Instead it should itself query the time when the submission is made. This can be done both on the application server or in the database insert/update statement itself.

Using the information in the [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html), here is how to make the table *Areas* keep the fields *TimeAdded* and *TimeUpdated* to the right time stamp itself (MySql version >= 5.6 is needed):

```
ALTER TABLE Areas
    MODIFY TimeAdded DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    MODIFY TimeUpdated DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

If your version of MySql does not support the above statement, then go for this alternative: create triggers that will give the same result:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insAreas BEFORE INSERT ON Areas FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.TimeAdded = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

CREATE TRIGGER updAreas BEFORE UPDATE ON Areas FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.TimeUpdated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

With this you do not have to update any dates, MySql will do it for you:

- No need to let PHP pass these dates in the SQL statements.
- No need to send dates to hidden inputs in the browser
- No need to correct times or timezones. MySql is the only one who updates these times, using the time on the server.

Comment: How its done in application server or in the db insert statement? I tried a lot but unable to find solution.

Comment: The best is the db insert statement, but you need first to specify which database engine you are using, as the syntax depends on that. Also provide the actual statement you currently have or tried with.

Comment: Actually hidden text field contains time of client who has logged in. Website built on php.  
`<input name="TIME" id="TIME" type="hidden" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set("".$row_CompanyDetails['TimeZone']."");echo "".date("Y-m-d G:i:s");?>">`

I need this to be stored in hidden field as this is for TimeAdded in table, & also there is TimeUpdated in table which is handle in mysql. 

So for TimeAdded i need thru hidden text field.

Comment: You really should put this information in your question. Please also specify **in your question** which database engine your are running on, and provide the PHP code you have for updating the the database.

Comment: It seems wrong that you first let PHP tell the browser which is the TimeAdded, and then you let the browser tell it PHP again. PHP should just remember this, or read it from the database. Since the user exists, it should already be there. I could help you, if you provided the code in your question.........

Comment: i m new to this. i would be glad and thankful for your help. & offence sorry.

Comment: Click on the edit link below your question, and add all the information I have asked about. I cannot help you if you do not give more information (SQL engine, table structure, PHP statements, ...)

Comment: Please show the PHP code that generates the page with the form, Please show the update statement, the insert statement, ... Questions have to be precise and give all the necessary information. We cannot guess what you have there.

Comment: Table Name: "Areas" Columns: ID, Name, AreaName, Position, TimeAdded, TimeUpdated, Deleted

Using php mysql. Hidden text field contains:

<input name="TIME" id="TIME" type="hidden" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set("".$row_CompanyDetails['TimeZone']."");echo "".date("Y-m-d G:i:s");?>">

Now lets say User open page at 2016-02-14 03:34:59 So at hidden field value is : 2016-02-14 03:34:59

So lets say user adds record After few seconds the record shows : 2016-02-14 03:34:59, where as it must show 2016-02-14 03:35:10+
So i need the exact value.

Comment: Could you put this in the question? It is difficult to read in the comments.

Comment: I m receiving an error when i do that.Error: Query error:
#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

Comment: Maybe you are in MySql version < 5.6? Can you tell me which version?

Comment: Server version: 5.5.39
What to do in this case?

Comment: I added an alternative solution in my answer.